# Compojure: access basic-authentication vars in route processing

Tags: clojure, basic-authentication, ring, compojure

I am writing a web API using Compojure with basic-authentication middleware.  The basic authentication part looks something like:

```
(defn authenticated? [id pass]
    (and (= id "blah")
         (= pass "blah"))
```

id and pass are passed in using the id:pass@website technique.  My problem is, I would like to access this id and pass further on down where the routes are processed with the various GET, PUT, POST, etc. headings.  But I can't figure out how to do this, and haven't had any luck googling around.

```
; i'd like to access id and pass here
(defroutes routes
    (GET "/" [] {:status 200 :headers {} :body "hi!"})
    ...)
```

I presume the solution is for the above to somehow "add" id and pass to some set of variables that can be accessed where the routes are processed, but I have no idea how to add nor to access them.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about https://github.com/remvee/ring-basic-authentication, the [authenticated? fn](https://github.com/remvee/ring-basic-authentication/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/basic_authentication.clj#L34) can return a truthly value that will be added to the request in the :basic-authentication. Something like (untested):

```
(defn authenticated? [id pass]
    (and (= id "gal") 
         (= pass "foo")
          {:user id :passwd pass}))

 (defroutes routes
     (GET "/" {the-user :basic-authentication} {:status 200 :headers {} :body (str "hi! Mr. " (:user the-user) " your password is " (:passwd the-user))})
     ...)
```

Comment: So how do you access the information down in your routes?

Comment: See the defroutes in my response. The third param on a route can be a destructuring form on the request.

Comment: Could you do this 'destructuring' in an example to show how to access the information?  Thanks.

Comment: I am already doing it. Look at the defroutes in the response. The third parameter on the GET {the-user :basic-authentication} is a destructuring form of the request map. See https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax for the Compojure specific syntax and http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring) for the supported Clojure's one.

Comment: Well what you wrote doesn't do anything because I tried it.  Show me how you would print out the id and pass down in the routes.

Comment: Well what I wrote works because I tried it. Show me how do you setup your project.clj, routes and the basic-auth middleware.

Comment: I get an "unable to resolve symbol: the-user" error.  Is there something else I'm lacking?  Something that allows me to access these parameters?

Comment: Without the code, the only thing that I can guess is that you misspelt something. Can you please share it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The return of the authenticated? method is associated in request map referenced by the key :basic-authentication. Here goes an example with a route that returns the user. You could, however, return a map or any other object and access it through :basic-authentication key.

```
(defn authenticated? [user password] user)

(defroutes require-auth-routes
   (GET "/return-user" request (.toString (:basic-authentication request)))

(def my-app
  (routes
    (-> require-auth-routes
        (wrap-basic-authentication authenticated?)))
```